# vb net + Check if Textbox1 is < Texbox2

Tags: vb.net

Waht is wrong with this ?
I have a simple form with textbox1 and textbox2 and a button.
When i put Textbox1 = 259 and textbox2 = 1500
I click, he say "You're number is too high"
I try 151 "You're number is too high"
I try 150 "ok"
I try 1500 "ok"
I try 1501 "You're number is too high"

Help.........

```
Public Class test

Private Sub test_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text > TextBox2.Text = True Then
        MsgBox("You're number is too high")
    Else
        MsgBox("ok")
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: are you trying to compare numeric values or strings that look like numbers.  If it is the former convert the strings to numbers and compare those.  Also remove the =True on the If.

Comment: You are comparing strings.  "259" is indeed larger than "1500", "2" sorts after "1".  Val() and CDec() can be useful to make the conversion.  But consider Decimal.TryParse(), also helps you check that the user actually entered a number and not, say, "asdf" or nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `Val` command.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
If Val(TextBox1.Text) > Val(TextBox2.Text) Then
  MsgBox("You're number is too high", "Wrong Input")
Else
  MsgBox("ok", "Input number") ' This also renames the msgbox itself, instead of just "error".
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Val(TextBox1.Text) > Val(TextBox2.Text) Then
        MsgBox("You're number is too high")
    Else
        MsgBox("ok")
    End If
```

You need to use the Val(string) function when converting string to a integer, double, decimal, etc.